# Стоит ли ставить дефис?

Tags: дефис

Подруга-социолог или подруга социолог?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: ***подруга-социолог***.

Дефис здесь ставится однозначно между двумя **нарицательными** существительными.

**Исключением** может быть определительное значение первого существительного (старик сторож, красавица невеста), но в данном случае  этого нет.

При такой записи на первом месте стоит определяемое **существительное**, а на втором – **приложение**.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111  п.2. Примечание